# Question about batter's position in batter's box prior to pitch

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating

Since I've read two different interpretations of this, I'm going to ask a question about the batter's box and the batter's orientation in it prior to the pitch, even if I'm pretty sure I know the answer.

Under OBR, it says that a batter's legal position in the box while addressing the pitcher is when both feet are within the lines of the box (the lines themselves being part of the box). So, simply, prior to hitting the pitch, this means the batter cannot even have a toe outside the white chalk lines, correct? I read on some shady site that you just need your foot touching the lines, meaning you can have your toes at least partially outside the lines. However, all other evidence seems to be the contrary. So, must the batter have both feet entirely within the lines, no toes/heels, etc outside the lines? I realize he's able to have a toe outside the line when actually hitting the ball, by the way.

Comment: The rules on this are never really enforced.  I've seen batters standing wherever they want.  I've never seen an umpire say anything.

Answer (score 1):

Both feet have to be in the batter's box if you swing and make contact with the ball and you have a foot outside of the box on the plate and or over the plate you can be ruled out if and only if the Umpire see this happen as far as your question both feet have to be in the Box for the picture to throw the ball to home plate